# Change an forEach depending on the locale

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

```
<% if (locale === 'pt') {
    data[i].info.pt.forEach(function(info) { %>
        <li><%= info %></li>
    <% }); %>
<% } else if (locale === 'en') {
    data[i].info.en.forEach(function(info) { %>
        <li><%= info %></li>
<% } else if (locale === 'es') {
    data[i].info.es.forEach(function(info) { %>
        <li><%= info %></li>
<% } %>
```

I have a variable called locale, which changes the value according to the language of the site, and I'm doing this forEach on an object, depending on the value of the locale, is there any way to make this better?

I was trying like this:

```
<% data[i].info. + locale + .forEach(function(info) { %>
 <li><% info %></li>
<% }); %>
```

But it seems that I can not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation):

```
<% data[i].info[locale].forEach(function(info) { %>
    <li><% info %></li>
<% }); %>
```

Comment: Cannot call method 'forEach' of undefined

Comment: What does `locale` equals? And are you sure that such property exists in `data[i].info` ?

Comment: sorry, i was using pt-br in one place and pt in other haha! THANKS!!